# Computer doesn't boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, crash

today my father ran his PC and it didn't boot. The screen is just black and says B4 on the bottom of screen. HDD's light flashes in the beginning so it does not seem to be a problem. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: What is the make and model number of the PC?

Comment: Turn power completely off, unplug, wait five minutes, plug back in and try again.  And as the unit starts, see if any identification of the BIOS brand and model is flashed on the screen -- record whatever you see, and report that along with the brand/model from the box labels, and anything you know about the OS version.

Answer (score 0):

So I have learnet abou BIOS error codes and B4 is an USB error so i unpulugged everything and it still didnt boot. But then i saw a micro SD plugged in and after unplugging the PC started normally. Now ill just check whats up with the card right...

Comment: This is an edit to your original question, not an answer. Edit your question.

Comment: @Xavierjazz, I think this is an answer.  The problem was a microSD card inadvertently left inserted; apparently the system was trying to boot from it.  After removing it, the problem was solved.